# Android SimpleAdapter add image to listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a little issue with setting an image to a list view using simple adapter. I'm getting the image from sdcard using ID from sqlite database, so the sqlite statement is working, the images are on sdcard,but if I try to set them in my listview, it's giving me an output :

```
resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.Bitmap@40566318
```

on LogCat. Here is the code I'm using to do it :

```
    String sqlite2 = "SELECT objectId FROM collectionmedias WHERE collectionId="+collId+" AND mediaType="+fronImage;
             Cursor bg = userDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(sqlite2);
             if (bg.getCount() == 0) {
                 Log.i("", "No Image file");
                 bg.close();
             } else if (bg.getCount() > 0) {
                 for (bg.move(0); bg.moveToNext(); bg.isAfterLast()) {

                    objectId = Integer.parseInt(bg.getString(bg.getColumnIndex("objectId")));
                    Log.i("","objectId : "+objectId);
                     path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                             + "/.MyApp/MediaCollection/" + objectId + ".png";
                     Log.v("","path: "+path);

                 }
             }

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inTempStorage = new byte[2*1024];

            Bitmap ops = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);



             hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put(IMAGE, ops);
                hm.put(TITLE, text);
                hm.put(CARDS_COUNT, cardsCount +" MyApp");
                items.add(hm);
        }

        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, items, R.layout.main_listview,
                new String[]{TITLE, CARDS_COUNT, IMAGE}, new int[]{ R.id.main_name, R.id.main_info, R.id.main_img});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it using this :  `path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyApp/MediaCollection/" + objectId + ".png";`

Comment: I had the same issue but my method is slightly different because i used the downloading image method instead of bitmap factory. Please have a look at my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450432/using-simpleadapter-with-image-for-listview