# Using simpleAdapter with image for listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a little problem with putting an image to a list view using simple adapter. I'm getting the image from my online server(AMAZON). After downloading the image based on the user id, i try to set them in my listview but nothing was display and no error is occured.

**Below is my code:**

```
// looping through All applicants
                for (int i = 0; i < applicant.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = applicant.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each JSON item in variable
                    String uid = c.getString(TAG_UID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String overall = c.getString(TAG_OVERALL);
                    String apply_datetime = c.getString(TAG_APPLY_DATETIME);
                    String photo = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    //HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    //IMAGE
                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key (value)
                    map.put(TAG_UID, uid);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_OVERALL, overall);
                    map.put(TAG_APPLY_DATETIME, apply_datetime);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    // applicantsList.add(map);

                    // LISTING IMAGE TO LISTVIEW
                    try {
                        imageURL = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO);

                        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(
                                "my url link/images/"
                                        + imageURL).getContent();
                        d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    map.put(TAG_PHOTO, d);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    applicantsList.add(map);
                }
```

As you can see, after i download the image. i set to listview using simpleAdapter below:

```
 SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            SignUpApplicantActivity.this, applicantsList,
                            R.layout.list_applicant, new String[] {
                                    TAG_UID, TAG_NAME, TAG_OVERALL,
                                    TAG_APPLY_DATETIME, TAG_PHOTO }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.applicantUid, R.id.applicantName,
                                    R.id.applicantOverall,
                                    R.id.apply_datetime, R.id.list_image });
                    // updating listView
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you check if the created `Drawable`s are null or not ? (e.g with a breakpoint or a log trace) ?

Comment: @fiddler Drawable is not null.

Comment: do not add tags (like "Android") to subject and do not add irrelevant tags (like "Eclipse").

Answer (score 1):

Did you called notifyDatasetChange() ? your adapter may not be invalidated if you don't call it.

Comment: i didnt call notifyDatasetChange(). I am not sure whether the method im using is it correct.

Comment: just after 
    setListAdapter(adapter);
call:
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

it may do the trick

Answer (score 1):

From the [SimpleAdapter documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) the image data is expected to be a resource ID or a string (an image URI) - see [setViewImage(ImageView,String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewImage%28android.widget.ImageView,%20java.lang.String%29)

I see 2 solutions:

1. Provide a URI in the data map, not a drawable.
2. Implement your own view binder to bind the drawable to the ImageView:

   ```
   adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {

       @Override
       public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {
           if(view.getId() == R.id.list_image) {
               ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
               Drawable drawable = (Drawable) data;
               imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: ok. from my code how do i change from drawable to uri? can you show me an example of it?

Comment: okok i give it a try and consult you again if i had any problem. thanks!

Comment: For my previous drawable.createfromsteam method is inside the doInBackground. for the 2nd suggestion where do i put it?

Comment: You can put it right after the instantiation of your adapter I think

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
         try{
            for (int i = 0; i < applicant.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = applicant.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each JSON item in variable
                String uid = c.getString(TAG_UID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String overall = c.getString(TAG_OVERALL);
                String apply_datetime = c.getString(TAG_APPLY_DATETIME);
                String photo = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key (value)
                map.put(TAG_UID, uid);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_OVERALL, overall);
                map.put(TAG_APPLY_DATETIME, apply_datetime);
                map.put(TAG_PHOTO, photo);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                applicantsList.add(map);
           } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
          return null;
      }
           SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        SignUpApplicantActivity.this, applicantsList,
                        R.layout.list_applicant, new String[] {
                                TAG_UID, TAG_NAME, TAG_OVERALL,
                                TAG_APPLY_DATETIME, TAG_PHOTO }, new int[] {
                                R.id.applicantUid, R.id.applicantName,
                                R.id.applicantOverall,
                                R.id.apply_datetime, R.id.list_image });
                // updating listView
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Maybe my code can help you!?!
I have made

> convertDrawable(int Integer)

and String.valueOf(convertDrawable(iconId))

> ```
> HashF.put(TAG_ID, String.valueOf(convertDrawable(iconId)));
> ```

```
private void getList(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            details = json.getJSONArray(TAG_LIST);

            for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject main = details.getJSONObject(i);
                Integer date = main.getInt(TAG_DATE);
                JSONArray nArray = main.getJSONArray(TAG_NOW);

                JSONObject detail = nArray.getJSONObject(0);
                Integer iconId = detail.getInt(TAG_ID);

                HashMap<String, String> HashF = new HashMap<String, String>();

                HashF.put(TAG_DATE, convertDate(date));
                HashF.put(TAG_ID, String.valueOf(convertDrawable(iconId)));

                fList.add(HashF);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        ListAdapter adapter = 
                new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), 
                        fList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{
                        TAG_DATE,
                        TAG_ID
                },
                new int[]{
                        R.id.datum,
                        R.id.icon_fore
                });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public static String convertDate(Integer Time) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = 
                new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "dd, MMMM", Locale.getDefault());

        Calendar kal = 
                Calendar.getInstance();

        kal.setTimeInMillis(Time * 1000L);
        sdf.setTimeZone(kal.getTimeZone());
        return sdf.format(kal.getTime());

    }


    public static int convertDrawable(int aId){
        int icon = 0;

        if(aId == 8300){
            icon = R.drawable.draw1;
        }
        if (aId >= 7010 && actualId < 7919){
            icon = R.drawable.draw2;
        }
        if (aId >= 2010 && actualId <3010) {
            icon = R.drawable.draw3;
        }
        if (aId >= 3010 && actualId < 4010) {
            icon = R.drawable.draw4;
        }
        if (aId >= 6010 && actualId < 7010) {
            icon = R.drawable.draw5;
        }
        if (aId >= 5010 && actualId < 6010) {
            icon = R.drawable.draw6;
        }
        if (aId == 3801){
            icon = R.drawable.draw7;
        }
        if (aId == 8032){
            icon = R.drawable.draw8;
        }
        if (aId == 8083){
            icon = R.drawable.draw9;
        }
        if (aId == 8704) {
            icon = R.drawable.draw10;
        }

        return icon;
    }
```

Anyway make a look at [Bitmap is not a Drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9490060/5281666)